# call rake The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I'm working with a Rails 2.3.2 application using rake to run a task.

This is part of my code:

```
 application_controller.rb

 def call_rake(task, options = {})
    options[:rails_env] ||= Rails.env
    args = options.map { |n, v| "#{n.to_s.upcase}='#{v}'" }
    system "/usr/bin/rake #{task} #{args.join(' ')} start"
  end
```

When running the line:

```
system "/usr/bin/rake #{task} #{args.join(' ')} start"
```

it doesn't run the task and say:

```
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I'm running this on Windows and already had to change & for start, is this Windows related or I'm missing something?

Some other code:

```
forbidden_file.rake

desc "Process CSV file"
task :process_file => :environment do
  forbidden_file = ForbiddenFile.find(ENV["csv"])
  forbidden_file.upload_file
end
```

Controller

```
...
call_rake :process_file, :csv => params[:files]
redirect_to forbidden_files_url
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes is windows related, in Windows rake location is something like `c:\ruby\ruby192\bin\rake`.
Do not use absolute paths to invoke commands if you want to be platform independent.

To run tasks from controller use:

```
%x[rake name_task]
```

or another way:

```
require 'rake'

Rake::Task.clear #clears tasks loaded in dev mode
YourApplicationName::Application.load_tasks # put your application name

class RakeController < ApplicationController

  def call_rake(task, options = {})
    Rake::Task[task].reenable # if you going to invoke the same task second time.
    Rake::Task[task].invoke(options)
  end

end
```